# Expand variables on config.xml PhoneGap

Tags: git, cordova, phonegap-build

Some plugins need to se values like api secret and more on the config.xml file but I dont want commits like that on my repo, instead I want place them on a different file and expand on config example

```
<widget ...>
...
    <plugin name="cordova-fabric-plugin" spec="~1.0.8">
        <variable name="FABRIC_API_KEY" value="blablabla" />
        <variable name="FABRIC_API_SECRET" value="blablabla_secret" />
    </plugin>
</widget>
```

How I can do something like

```
<widget ...>
...
    <plugin name="cordova-fabric-plugin" spec="~1.0.8">
        <variable name="FABRIC_API_KEY" value="${FABRIC_API_KEY}" />
        <variable name="FABRIC_API_SECRET" value="${FABRIC_API_SECRET}" />
    </plugin>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be awesome if there was such a simple feature, but alas the only option I know at this point would be to use hooks.

You can utilize the `before_build` and `after_build` events to effectively edit your config before compiling, and then change it back once the process is complete.

This is untested code, but it would look something like this:

**/scripts/before_build/config_variables.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var fs = require('fs');
var variables = require('./../../.variables');

module.exports = function(context) {
  var configPath = 'config.xml';
  var configBackupPath = 'config.xml.backup';

  var config = fs.readFileSync(configPath, 'ascii');
  fs.writeFileSync(configBackupPath, config, 'ascii');

  var tempConfig = config.replace(/\${(.*?)}/g, function (match, variableName) {
    if (variables.hasOwnProperty(variableName)) {
      return variables[variableName];
    } else {
      return match;
    }
  });

  fs.writeFileSync(configPath, tempConfig, 'ascii');
}
```

**/scripts/after_build/config_variables.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function(context) {
  var configPath = 'config.xml';
  var configBackupPath = 'config.xml.backup';

  var realConfig = fs.readFileSync(configBackupPath, 'ascii');

  fs.writeFileSync(configPath, realConfig, 'ascii');
  fs.unlink(configBackupPath);
}
```

**/.variables.js**

```
module.exports = {
  FABRIC_API_KEY: 'blablabla',
  FABRIC_API_SECRET: 'blablabla_secret',
};
```

And finally, you would add these hooks to the `config.xml` file itself:

```
<hook type="before_build" src="scripts/before_build/config_variables.js" />
<hook type="after_build" src="scripts/after_build/config_variables.js" />
```

Now when you run `$ phonegap build {platform}` it will pull from the object you export in `.variables.js`, overwrite the config, build/compile, and replace the edited config from the backup.

I actually went a step further in my own usage and used command line arguments to pull in different variables for multiple app flavors :)

One last tip, make sure your hooks are executable.

Comment: Do you know if the after build hooks is always called, even if the build fails for whatever reason (eg. CTRL+C)

Comment: Unfortunately they are not, so if the build DOES fail you would end up with an altered config.xml.  Luckily if you're tracking with a VCS that's an easy fix, but still inconvenient to say the least :/